# How to integrate API Gateway to call Lambda function with a parameter?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

I have a react app that uploads a file to S3. When the user press a button to extract text out of the file, the app will call a GET to API Gateway and send the file name as parameter. This will trigger the lambda function to extract the text from the file on the S3. But I am stuck with the API that needs to call the Lambda function. 
 
I followed this tutorial from AWS: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-lambda.html#api-as-lambda-proxy-expose-get-method-with-query-strings-to-call-lambda-function

This is what the response is what I get when I test the API call:

```
Received response. Status: 403, Integration latency: 3 ms
Sun Oct 25 13:29:26 UTC 2020 : Endpoint response headers: {Date=Sun, 25 Oct 2020 13:29:26 GMT, Content-Length=130, Connection=keep-alive, x-amzn-RequestId=d8eab391-05a7-44f2-9721-ce67939a9514}
Sun Oct 25 13:29:26 UTC 2020 : Endpoint response body before transformations: <AccessDeniedException>
  <Message>Unable to determine service/operation name to be authorized</Message>
</AccessDeniedException>

Sun Oct 25 13:29:26 UTC 2020 : Method response body after transformations: <AccessDeniedException>
  <Message>Unable to determine service/operation name to be authorized</Message>
</AccessDeniedException>

Sun Oct 25 13:29:26 UTC 2020 : Method response headers: {X-Amzn-Trace-Id=Root=1-5f957db6-4e36be9def67f8157b8467c5, Content-Type=application/json}
Sun Oct 25 13:29:26 UTC 2020 : Successfully completed execution
Sun Oct 25 13:29:26 UTC 2020 : Method completed with status: 200
```

Every single post that I read about this error said that the problem is that my HTTP method must be a POST, BUT IT IS? Here in the screenshot of my settings:

[Screenshot of my API integration request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKDoT.png)

So my question is, how do I fix this so that my API can call my Lambda function and return the text back to the app?

Comment: What is `myLambdaRole`?

Comment: Execution role for the lambda function. It has full lambda and cloudwatch access, as well as allowed to invoke a lambda function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AWS Service` integration type is to ingrate the api gateway with any AWS service. Even though a lambda is a AWS feature, there is a `Lambda` integration type for this specifically there for integrating lambdas. I think lambda integration type is the suitable one in this case.

You can pass the file name in the GET request as well (for example as a query string parameter).

If you like to use the `AWS Service` integration type, make sure to add permission for api gateway to invoke the lambda. you need to add this permission in Lambda IAM Role's trust policy.

Comment: is there any reason why you are using `AWS Service` integration type over `Lambda` integration type

Comment: Hi, yea the reason for using that instead of lambda integration was the fact that AWS did it in the tutorial so I assumed that it would be "more correct"

Comment: did you check the cloudwatch logs for lambda, is the request reaching there

Comment: Amazing. I changed it to Lambda integration and it works. THANKS Arun!! You must go help AWS to write better tutorials! xD

Comment: Dont worry about it. The only thing i cant think of is, the lambda's role should allow the api gateway service to invoke itself using the trust policy. can you post the lambda's IAM role's trust policy

Comment: Sure!
`{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": [
          "lambda.amazonaws.com",
          "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
        ]
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}`

Comment: does the api gateway got permissions to invoke the lambda. in the tutorial, "Create an API Gateway assumable IAM role" section has the steps to do that.

Comment: Yes it did have permission to invoke. But yea, I changed from AWS service to the normal Lambda integration and it worked! Thanks a lot